# CGridView change the pagination position

Tags: gridview, yii

I simply want to duplicate the pagination position to the top of the list, is there any Yii way to do that or I just have to use javascript to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple: just look code at CGridView, or document on yii's sites:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'template' => "{pager}\n{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}",
//
);
```

Comment: @bool.dev, sorry I don't understant your reply.

Comment: i thought having pager twice in the template was a typo

Comment: If you want pagination on top and bottom of page ,you need to write pager twice. if not use  $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'template' => "{pager}\n{summary}\n{items}",
); so that it will show pagination only on top of page.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to render gridview components as per requirements:

```
$myGrid = $this->widget();
```

$this->widget(); returns an object, we can then use this object to render different components on the page wherever required.

```
$myGrid->renderPager();
echo '<div>My other content</div>'; 
$myGrid->renderItems();
```

Other render methods can be found in the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView)